# Leave One Out Cross Validation "by hand" using a "for" cycle in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, cross-validation

I'm trying to use a `for` cycle in order to replicate the behavior of the `cv.glm()` function in the `boot` library:

```
library(ISLR)
attach(Weekly) # this has 1089 rows

cutoff <- .5 # determines the prediction

wrong <- 0 # we'll record the number of wrong predictions here
for (i in 1:1089) {
  fit <- glm(Direction~Lag1+Lag2, data=Weekly[-i,], family=binomial) # leaves out the i-th observation
  prob <- predict(fit,Weekly[i,],type="response")
  if (prob<cutoff) pred <- "Down" else pred <- "Up"
  if (pred!=Direction[i]) wrong <- wrong +1
}

wrong / 1089 # approximately 45% LOOCV error rate

# Let's try the same with the cv.glm()
library(boot)
cv.glm(Weekly,glm(Direction~Lag1+Lag2, data=Weekly, family=binomial))$delta # approximately 25%, why??
```

As you can see, my problem is that I don't get similar results in the two cases.
My best guess is that I might be confused about the meaning of `delta` in the case of a logistic regression.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see the last example in `cv.glm` : use the cost function `cost <- function(r, pi = 0) mean(abs(r-pi) > 0.5)` and `K=nrow(Weekly)`

Comment: ps: don't use `attach`